# Problems with Kentico editor/WYSIWYG

Tags: kentico, kentico-12

We've just switched from K7 to Kentico 12 and having some problems with the editor.

1. When formatting code in an external editor for a page and pasting it into the source code, it's stripping out all formatting, so the source code is 1 long list of code as apposed to keeping the formatting - tabbed lines etc (This worked fine in K7)
2. When pasting into the WYSIWYG from Word, instead of creating new paragraphs it just br />br /> after every line (Even when using the 'Paste from Word' or 'Paste as plain text' options).

Any help solving these would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The WYSIWYG editor will, by default, "fix" any formatting which is not correct.  It's very strict in nature as well and IMHO doesn't work well at all for anyone with advanced knowledge of HTML.

My suggestion is to use either static text web parts for your more advanced HTML and leave the editable text for your simple HTML and content editors.

There is also some configuration you can do to the CKEditor by modifying the `\<root>\CMS\CMSAdminControls\CKeditor\config.js` file.  See the [CKEditor documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_configuration.html#using-the-configjs-file) for more information on that.